# Navigate through a button

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, master-detail

I have a Master Detail View application. On the detailView I have a welcome screen, and on the tableView I have list of employees. When I click on the employee, call a seperate view on top of DetailView with the below code.

```
[_dtController.navigationController pushViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"OBViewController"] animated:YES];
```

I can go back from the Navigation bar button, but I have a button on my OBViewController, through which I have to go back. Can anyone tell me how to navigate and go back from a button.

Comment: please post the code you have tried using to make the button navigate back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to take a look at [Apple's UINavigationController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Specifically, the below item:

```
 - (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

This can be used from any view within a view to get your desired outcome. It's important to note the difference between "push" and "pop" with regards to the UINavigationController hierarchy. To add a view, you *push* it to the stack. To remove it, you *pop* it off the stack.